# How can we access data stored in django forms?

Tags: python-3.x, django, forms

I am using the following code to get contact number and email from user:

```
 Contact_Number = forms.RegexField(regex="[0-9]",min_length=11,max_length=15)
 email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
```

Is there any way to access the user contact number, using the user name later on. I am able to excess email using the "user.email" but not the contact number.

Answer (score 0):

In your user app

#forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(help_text='Enter valid email ')

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','email','password1','password2']
```

if you have to add an extra field then

#forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name=forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=False,help_text='Enter Your Name ')
    last_name=forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=False,help_text='Enter Your Surname')
    email=forms.EmailField(help_text='Enter valid email ')
    phone_number=forms.IntegerField(help_text='Enter valid phone number ')

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','first_name','last_name','email','phone_number','password1','password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user=super(UserRegisterForm,self).save(commit=True)
        user.first_name= self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.phone_number=self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

#user/register.html

```
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="'border-bottom mb-4">Register </legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn-outline-info" type="submit"> Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form
```

hope it works if not then note me

Comment: sorry, yesterday I tested only the first_name and last_name fields. Now, I placed phone_number attribute by copying your code but it is not working. Moreover, when I replaced "email" with "emails", just to check whether it works on it or not, it did not work too, I also added 'user.emails = self.cleaned_data['emails']'

Comment: I have solved this problem, your solution leads me to solve this problem. I was actually using the default user database and that doesn't have any phone number field so was not saving it.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html go to this link